# Wordpress Mobile Menu not working and header text jumping

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have been doing some fixes to this wordpress site: http://avphotobooth.com and trying to make the responsive menu work as well fix the header text on the mobile version but having problems doing so - it is a Salient Theme, but can not get support for it due to it being an older version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell you have everything working except the mobile menu icon is showing on desktop? So just use CSS to hide it and display it on mobile only.

```
#toggle-nav{
    display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 990px) {
    #toggle-nav{
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Just modify the 990px to the width of the site you want the button to show again.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your help, I was struggling with this one.

Comment: That's great! Could you accept my answer so it get's a tick?

Comment: Ok just realized iPhone 6 plus menu and home page looks great. iPhone 6 menu not working and page is greyed out part of the way?